Playwright Browser Launch issue
playwright._impl._errors.TargetClosedError: Browser.new_page: Target page, context or browser has been closed
Been launching the chromium browser instance on my aws lambda with no issues until recently faced this kind of issue.
The browser fails to initialize and is causing my whole functionality down.
I've built the local image and tested it on docker, the app functions fine. This issue is only occuring on aws lambda
My browser launch configurations are :
    async with async_playwright() as playwright:
        browser_path = find_chromium_path()
        executable_path = f"{browser_path}/chrome-linux/chrome"
        # Local development
        if not os.path.exists(executable_path):
            executable_path = None

        browser = await playwright.chromium.launch(headless=True,
                                                   executable_path=executable_path,
                                                   args=[
                                                       "--no-sandbox",
                                                       "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
                                                       "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
                                                       "--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas",
                                                       "--disable-gpu",
                                                       "--single-process",
                                                       "--no-zygote",
                                                       "--disable-audio-output",
                                                       "--disable-software-rasterizer",
                                                       "--disable-webgl",
                                                       "--disable-web-security",
                                                       "--disable-features=LazyFrameLoading",
                                                       "--disable-features=IsolateOrigins",
                                                       "--disable-background-networking"
                                                   ]
                                                   )

Is there any workaround for this problem?

Spent 19 hours on this as well... The answer is in the args. The only args you need are:
args=['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox','--disable-gpu','--single-process']

That should prevent the error! Lmk if it works

--single-process and --no-zygote flags made the stuff working for me on AWS Lambda with playwright v1.46.0
